# Before Insert Trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, constraints, functional-dependencies

I am trying to create a trigger to represent a Functional Dependency in my MySQL table

this is the FD I'm trying to represent

Every droid of the same type has the same main skill.

dtype->mainskill

here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Droid(
    cname CHAR(30),
    dtype CHAR(30),
    mainskill CHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (cname),
    FOREIGN KEY (cname) REFERENCES Characters (cname)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Here is the trigger I created I'm not sure if the logic is correct but i'm getting syntax errors on execution any ideas?

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1
BEFORE INSERT
   ON Droid FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
       SELECT * from Droid (
       Select dtype t, mainskill m from Droid where t=NEW.dtype AND m!=NEW.m;

    )
)

    PRINT 'TYPE -> SKILL FD DOESN'T HOLD'
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO Droid 
    SELECT * FROM inserted



END;
```

Comment: Any ideas? Ive tried multiple variations keeps giving a syntax error !

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use a trigger instead of a table and a foreign key?

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. What is the error message & what did you learn googling it?